# Удаление header Server в apache

Tags: apache2

Нужно удалить соответствующий заголовок полностью. Пробовал:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
Header unset Server
```

но не помогло. Apache 2.2.12, `mod_security` для него не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью удалить заголовок из ответа не получится

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ServerTokens:

> Setting ServerTokens to less than minimal is not recommended because
>   it makes it more difficult to debug interoperational problems. Also
>   note that disabling the Server: header does nothing at all to make
>   your server more secure. The idea of "security through obscurity" is a
>   myth and leads to a false sense of safety.

Вольный перевод:

> Установка ServerTokens до менее чем минимального уровня не
>   рекомендуется, поскольку сделает более трудным отладку проблем
>   межоперационных взаимодействий. Также обратите внимание, что
>   отключение заголовка Server: не сделает ваш сервер более безопасным.
>   Идея "безопасности через неясность" - миф и приводит к ложному чувству
>   безопасности.

Но если вот прям очень нужно, то я бы рекомендовал взять исходный код Apache, найти код обработки конфигурации касательно опции ServerTokens, посмотреть на что он влияет, посмотреть на что влияет то, на что влияет опция (таких итераций может быть несколько), и убрать полностью формирование заголовка `Server` из исходного кода. Далее собрать и заменить в системе ванильный бинарник Apache на модифицированный. При первом же автоматическом обновлении "заплатка" слетит, вероятно

С помощью `mod_headers`-директив вроде `Header unset Server` вы его не уберете по той же причине. Apache представляется собой клиенту, потому что это Apache, и просто так убрать это без модификации исходного кода или без установки модулей третьей стороны не получится, такова идея разработчиков